# Keyboard overlay textfield, not working focusNode in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text field on the page which is located at the very bottom. `resizeToAvoidBottomInset value: false`. I added a `focuseNode` so that when the field is clicked, it will be in focus. But when I click on this text field, the keyboard overlaps and nothing is visible because the text field is at the very bottom and the page does not scroll when the keyboard opens. How can I make the text field visible when opening the keyboard? If I use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`, then the page scrolls, but between the keyboard and the widget there is a large padding that is set at the bottom of the page and I cannot remove this padding.

**main page**

```
const Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: FormPage(),
      ),
```

**body**

```
class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? paid;
  final bool? init;
  final Function(bool) parking;
  final Function(int) valueChange;
  const PaidParking({
    Key? key,
    required this.parking,
    required this.paid,
    required this.init,
    required this.valueChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FormPage > createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage > {
  FocusNode myFocusNodeName = FocusNode();

  final TextEditingController controller =
      TextEditingController(text: '€59 per h');

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      paidParking = widget.parkingInit ?? false;
      controller.text =
          '€${widget.paidInit != null ? (widget.paidInit! / 100) : 2} per h';
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    myFocusNodeName.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myFocusNodeName.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Opacity(
                opacity: paidParking ? 1 : 0.7,
                child: const Text(
                  'Form Page',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: constants.FontFamily.AvenirLtStd,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              switcher,
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          paidParking ? parkingValueGet() : const SizedBox(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void changeValue(bool operation, {bool editing = false}) {
    final String value = controller.text;

    double num = double.parse(
      value
          .replaceAll('€', '')
          .replaceAll('per', '')
          .replaceAll('h', '')
          .replaceAll(' ', ''),
    );

    if (!editing) {
      if (num <= 0 && !operation) return;

      operation ? num += 0.05 : num -= 0.05;
      controller.text = '€${num.toStringAsFixed(2)} per h';
      widget.paidValueChange((num * 100).round());
    } else {
      num = double.parse(controller.text);
      controller.text = '€${num.toStringAsFixed(2)} per h';
      num = double.parse(
        value
            .replaceAll('€', '')
            .replaceAll('per', '')
            .replaceAll('h', '')
            .replaceAll(' ', ''),
      );
      widget.valueChange((num * 100).round());
    }
  }

  Widget parkingValueGet() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        InkWell(
          onTap: () => changeValue(false),
          child: _circleBox(false),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
              width: 120,
              child: TextField(
                controller: controller,
                focusNode: myFocusNodeName,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: FontFamily.AvenirBook,
                  color: constants.Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                ),
                onSubmitted: (value) => changeValue(true, editing: true),
                onEditingComplete: () => changeValue(true, editing: true),
                keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                  signed: true,
                ),
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9.]")),
                ],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.white, height: 1, width: 115),
          ],
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () => changeValue(true),
          child: _circleBox(true),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _circleBox(bool operation) {
    return Container(
      height: 23,
      width: 23,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: constants.Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        operation ? '+' : '-',
        style: constants.Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get switcher => Opacity(
        opacity: paidParking ? 1 : 0.7,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              paidParking = !paidParking;
            });
            widget.paidParking(paidParking);
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 20,
            alignment:
                paidParking ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
            width: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: paidParking ? constants.Colors.purpleMain : Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.5),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
              child: Container(
                height: 17,
                width: 17,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: paidParking ? Colors.white : const Color(0xff484452),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First I can recommend you to do some changes.

1. Remove **setState()** method calling inside **initState()**(have no
   effect).
2. Remove totally the part of the below code. When you are using **TexField**
   inside a **StatefulWidget**, every time the keyboard opened it will
   recall your **build()** method and in this case, will add multiple focus
   listeners on each **build()** method call, also each focus listener is
   calling the **setState()** method which is triggering **build()** method
   again. This is kind of an infinity loop. I wonder when you open the
   keyboard, does your app stuck or stop working smoothly?

   **myFocusNodeName.addListener(() {
   setState(() {});
   });**

Comment: The app works fine, but I can't scroll the page and half of the widget is hidden behind the keyboard.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what it looks like

Comment: I can't scroll the widget, raise it up

Comment: First please try to do my requested changes then try to see if it works, if not please also attach **Scaffold** widget code part top of this **Widget**. Thanks!